# Пользователь вводит число N, после чего вводит N чисел. Верно ли, что они упорядочены по возрастанию?

Tags: python, for, while

Задание по Python, выданное на этапе, когда изучены только for, while, if

Вот, что у меня получилось. Проблема в том, что программа выводит положительный ответ, когда i нулевое меньше, чем i n-ное, игнорируя промежуточные значения (например, при вводе чисел 4, 3, 2, 5). Прошу помощи.

```
if n<=1:
    print('Введите количество, большее, чем 1')
else:
    lst = [int(input('Введите число: ')) for i in range(n)]
    for k in range(len(lst)):
        k=0
        if lst[i]<lst[i+1]:
            print('Числа упорядочены по возрастанию')
            break # если убрать break  - выводит n раз "Да"
            k+=1
        else:
            print('Числа не упорядочены по возрастанию')
            break # если убрать break  - выводит n раз "Нет"
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flag = True
for k in range(len(lst) - 1):
    if lst[k] >= lst[k+1]:
        print('Числа не упорядочены по возрастанию')
        flag = False
        break
if flag:
   print('Числа упорядочены по возрастанию')
```

А вот k внутри цикла for изменять не надо

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне пояснить, как новичку: почему необходимо вычесть 1 из длины списка?

И еще: при вводе одинаковых чисел Ваш код все равно выдает, что числа упорядочены по возрастанию. И та же проблема остается нерешенной: если первое введенное число меньше, чем n-ное, программа дает результат 'Числа упорядочены по возрастанию', игнорируя промежуточные значения (например, при вводе чисел 2, 1, 3).

Comment: вычесть 1 - потому что на последнем шаге проверяются предпоследний и последний элементы, иначе будет выход за границы списка. С `>` проверяется неубывание, для строгого возрастания, если вам оно требуется, нужно `>=`. Кроме того, я скопировал, не заметив, что в сравнении используются индексы i вместо k. Исправил